# cannot find QAudioDeviceInfo availableDevices, in all environments

Tags: qt, audio, qt4, vmware

I am running my qt4.8 gui (which uses QAudioOutput to play a .wav) on two types of workstations.

```
1.  A windows computer via Oracle VM VirtualBox Redhat- linux
2.  A Linux computer via VMware workstation- linux
```

When I run gui on windows VB the gui plays audio just fine and prints no errors. When I (try to) play on VMWare the app hangs in limbo and I get the following error:

```
Raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.
Using null output device, none available
```

I throw the Raw audio format error when defaultOutputDevice is not supported. The null output device error is generated from qt code.

When I add the following code:

```
 foreach (const QAudioDeviceInfo &deviceInfo, 
    QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput))
    {
        qDebug() << "Device name: " << deviceInfo.deviceName();
    }
```

On VirtualBox I get:

```
Device name: “default:CARD=I82801AAICH”
Device name: “sysdefault:CARD=I82801AAICH”
Device name: “default”
```

On VMWare it doesn’t print any available devices.

when I run command lspci|grep -i audio
on VirtualBox i get:

```
multimedia audio controller:Intel corporation 82801AA AC'97 (rev 01)
```

on VMWare i get:

```
VMWare HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
```

Also I can use the play command on both workstations from command line and the wav file plays. Aditionally I do not currently have aplay rpms installed for troubleshooting. I also checked .vmx file for audio setup and it matches VMWare recomendations. I would also mention I am using pulseaudio version 6 on virtualBox and 10 on VMWare, but I wouldnt think this is the problem.

Any idea what could be causing this error to hit on VMWare redhat workstation, and anything else I can look into to troubleshoot? Is this a library or compatability issue?

---

Updated:

code that I use to set up device:

```
    //set bytes to buffer
    qbuff=new QBuffer();
    qbuff->setData(qbyte);
    qbuff->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); 

    //set expected wav format
    format.setFrequency(48000);
        format.setChannels(1);
        format.setSampleSize(16);
        format.setSampleRate(48000);
        format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
        format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
        format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    foreach (const QAudioDeviceInfo &deviceInfo, QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput))
    {
        qDebug() << " Device name: " << deviceInfo.deviceName();
    }
QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format))
    {
            qWarning()<<"raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.";
    }
    audioOutput  = new QAudioOutput(format,this);
```

Comment: Usually you use a `format` or a default one with `QAudioDevice` , that format might not be supported on the Linux/VmWare side, this is provided as you assured the audio device can play in the box.

Comment: And I wish you shared the code part where you initialize the device

Comment: @MohammadKanan updated with full setup code

Comment: Now its clear. your are getting the warning that you coded when the format is not supported! but the real problem is that you are not caring .. just continue initializing the device with unsupported format!

Comment: `QAudioDeviceInfo` has a method `supportedformates` that lets you know a head which format to use. try that.

Comment: Yes but at this point im just trying to figure out why it isnt supported on one machine and it is on another. And more troublesome to me is that I cannot find any availableDevices on VMWare machine. I tried format = info.nearestFormat(format); in unsupported format block but didnt make a difference

Comment: Thats an _OS dependent_ .. nothing to do with Qt device .. `nearestformat` I know it does not always work!

Comment: I would imagine the format issue is irrelevant if i cant figure out how to return availableDevices that qt can understand on VMWare first

Comment: You already did that with ` QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput))`

Comment: But the _availability_ of that device to qt does not guarantee it is compatible with the _format_ you are _forcing_ it to use.

Comment: Appologize if my post wasnt clear but it returns devices on windows VB and thats when the audio plays. It doesnt return any devices on VMWare and doesnt play

Comment: That turns to be pure VmWare issue!

Comment: So definately not a library issue or rpm version or anything like that? Just a compatability or setup issue from VMWare?

Comment: I think so, did you say you can play audio to the device from outside qt in VmWare .. while qt is failing to find the device..?

Comment: You probably need to check how VmWare interface to host OS to use the device!

Comment: yes. I can play the wav file from command line in VMWare box

Comment: Try to catch the device in qt directly .. dont use `default` .. it could simply be possible

Comment: not sure what exactly you mean by "Try to catch device in qt". I would imagine the fact that availableDevices returns empty overrides any further qt code that i could try. Maybe i will just  use qt to call command line to play at this point

Comment: there is a second constructor for `QAudioOutput` that can takes `QAudioDeviceInfo ` ... that is `QAudioOutput::QAudioOutput(const QAudioDeviceInfo &audioDevice ...`

Comment: but what would i use for QAudioDeviceInfo if my forEach(QAudioDeviceInfo, availableDevices) returns null? I dont see how that could possibly work. unless im missing something?

Comment: Thats just away to debug it.